# getOwnPropertyDescriptor of a closured var

Tags: javascript, closures

EDIT: What I am trying to do is safely access a the information about a variable without causing any side effects. "var x = 5;" can safely be changed to "var x; x = 5;". "var x" cannot however be changed to "var x; x" I believe, because under certain circumstances that could call a getter, hence me wanting to do "var x; Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(?, "x")"

If I have a var:

```
function x()
{
var y = whatever;
}
```

Is it possible to access its property descriptor?:

```
function x()
{
var y = whatever;
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(???, "y");
}
```

Comment: A variable does not have a property descriptor since it's not a property. What kind of information do you hope to get from something like that (if it existed)? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Every variable is an `Object`, but you have to use `new Object(y)` for it to *possibly* work with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`. (Warning: This *might* not work!)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: A *variable* is certainly *not* an object. A "variable" is language concept, an "object" is a *value*.

Comment: @FelixKling Therefore, I use `new Object(y)`. But it might not work anyway. I was about to edit it.

Comment: Does it not become a property of the surrounding context? When you do with({a:5}) { var a = 6 } a is certainly a property, and when you do vm.runInContext("var x = 8", context) x becomes a property of context

Comment: @Francisco: There are two types of environments: Declarative and object environments. Only the global environment and environments created with `with` are object environments. Declarative environments don't bind to objects (at least not in a way exposed to the user). See http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1

Comment: @FelixKling It also works with the `arguments` object. Try this: `(function(){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(arguments,0);})(6);`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: No surprise here, since the value of `arguments` is an object. Note that you are getting the property descriptor of `0`, i.e. the a property of the `arguments` object. But the OP wants to get the descriptor of `arguments` (`y` in their example) itself.

Comment: If I am in a declarative environment, am I then safe to reference some var "x" without possibly triggering a side effect (such as a getter). Essentially "var x; x;" ~= "var x"?

Comment: I *think* so, but I'm not 100% sure. If that's your actual issue, I recommend to update your question.

Comment: @FelixKling It is a step closer to what the OP wants. Probably `function x(){var y = whatever; (function(){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(arguments,0);})(y); }` will *almost* do the trick.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: The property descriptor wouldn't tell you anything about the original variable. I think you're grabbing at straws here.

Comment: @FelixKling "A variable is certainly not an object. A "variable" is language concept, an "object" is a value." --> I disagree! An `Object` is a structure, while a variable is a 'named pointer to the values in memory'.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Not really, since it still returns the property descriptor of property `0` of `arguments`, which is independent of the value of `arguments[0]`.

Comment: @FelixKling That's the closest I can get. Therefore saying "*almost* do the trick".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: That would do as much of the trick as this would: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor({foo:"bar"}, "foo");` Neither tell you anything about the variable.

Comment: @sixfingeredman I'm not saying the oposite, I'm just saying that I'm trying to reach there, but the 'solution' I gave is the closest I can get. But, it isn't *that* inaccurate, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Except that you're saying that it's a step closer, when it isn't. You could pass any arbitrary object and property to `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, and you'd be just as close.

Comment: FWIW, this is the algorithm used to resolve variables: http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.2.1. It's not super detailed, but there is nothing that indicates something is done by/to the actual value by just referencing the variable. `GetBindingValue` also seems to be relevant: http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1

Comment: @sixfingeredman Still, I won't deny that. Therefore saying *'solution'* (notice the quotes).

Comment: @FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI: This sounds like an XY Problem. What are you trying to achieve in the end? Property descriptors just don't make sense here since local variables have no concept of enumerability, configurability or (non-)writability.

Comment: @sixfingeredman What I'm trying to achieve is a (safe) code transformation that won't have any harmful side effects. Namely, I know that var x = 5 can safely (and I suppose arguably is the same as) var x; x = 5; I want to know if I can do the same for var x; -> var x; x; I thought I could not, which is why I wanted to do var x; Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(?, "x"), which would not accidentally call any getters/etc.

Comment: There's no reason to be worried about calling getters on local variables since there's no way to create them. Reading local variables has no side effect.

Comment: Well, if I have "var y = { x: get() { do_something_crazy(); return 4 } }; with(y) { var x; var z; }", then "var z;" -> "var z; z;" IS safe but "var x; x;" is NOT safe right? In other words, its runtime dependent and thus the transformation at least cannot be safely done in withs?

Comment: That's true, but then why not just get the property descriptor from `y`?

Comment: ...to put it simply, no, you can not get property descriptors without referencing some object that holds some property.

Comment: In reference to why not just get it from y, its because this is a transpiler thats doing all this, so it doesn't know about y (since its runtime dependent).

Comment: @Francisco: The transpiler should know whether it's in a `with` context or not.